# Mobile Advertising question (iOS)

Tags: ios, ads

Is there an ad network that allows you to run customized in-house ads that are dependent on the user's location?  I mean, as an example, could I create 10 in-house ads and tell the network something like:

"If the user is within 50 miles of City X, show these 4 ads and if he is within 50 miles of City Y, show these 6 ads."

Does this type of service exist?

Comment: How is this in any way a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Mopub](http://www.mopub.com/) would be a good choice for you.  They do in-house ads with geolocation.  Also, if you are investigating which advertising platform to go with I am aggregating a list at [AppSDKs.com](http://www.appsdks.com/?category_id=6)

Answer (score 0):

Searching google with the same question here. Looks like some do show house ads but not as we whished:

- [Google Ads SDK for iOS](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/mobile/ads/kb/#houseads) (only shows house ads when no matching ad is available and an alternateUrl is supplied by you, seems to not take into account user location)
- [AdWhirl (by AdMob)](http://www.admob.com/appdevs) (seems it does not take into account user location)
- iAds does not seem to offer house ads functionality

Guess the search is still on :(, but ruled out some